# Ansible: register variable with loop

Tags: ansible, linux, cicd

What’s the best way to use registered variable ‘audit_tools’ to check if all items are own by root ?
Do I need to use Jinja2 filter or something ?

Thanks

```
- name: Verify audit tools are own by root user.
  block: 
    - name: check if audit tools are own by root user.
      become: true
      stat:
        path: "/sbin/{{ audit_loop }}"
      loop:
        - auditctl
        - aureport
        - ausearch
        - autrace
        - auditd
        - audispd
        - augenrules
      loop_control:
        loop_var: audit_loop
      register: audit_tools

    debug:
      msg: “one or more tools are not own by root.”
    When: .....



  Rescue
     ......
```

Answer (score 6):

Q: **"*Check if all items are own by root.*"**

A: Put the list of the tools into the variable *audit_tools*. Compare the length of the lists. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    audit_tools:
      - auditctl
      - aureport
      - ausearch
      - autrace
      - auditd
      - audispd
      - augenrules
  tasks:
    - block:
        - stat:
            path: "/sbin/{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ audit_tools }}"
          register: result
        - assert:
            that: no_audit_tools == no_owner_root
            fail_msg: "One or more tools are not own by root."
          vars:
            no_audit_tools: "{{ audit_tools|length }}"
            no_owner_root: "{{ result.results|
                               json_query('[?stat.pw_name==`root`]')|
                               length }}"
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "Rescue: audit tools not owned by root."
```

If not all items are owned by root *assert* will fail and the *block* will proceed to the *rescue* section

```yaml
TASK [assert] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: no_audit_tools == no_owner_root
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: One or more tools are not own by root.

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'Rescue: audit tools not owned by root.'
```

---

Q: **"*This solution requires [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) to be installed. Is there an alternative solution?*"**

A: Yes. It is. Use Jinja filter [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr)

```yaml
            no_owner_root: "{{ result.results|
                               selectattr('stat.pw_name', 'eq', 'root')|
                               list|length }}"
```

Comment: Hi,  with your example, where do you put the audit tools list ? Can you explain the length of 'vars' ?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not sure I understand about the length string. Would this work? `code` "{{ result.results.map (attribute '?stat.pw_name==`root`] ) |
                               length }}" `code`

Comment: See the complete playbook. Take a look at [length](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#length) and [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries).

Comment: This solution requires a 'jmespath' to be installed on the OS. Is there an alternative solution to this ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Open new questions if you have other issues.